# html DOM: good test webpages to test encoding/decoding

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

What I'm doing is:

- via javascript, reading the DOM of webpage
- converting to json string
- sending to python as ajax
- in Python, json decoding the string into object

What I want is for any text that is part of the json to be in unicode to avoid any character issues. I used to use beautifulsoup for this:

```
from bs4 import * 
from bs4.dammit import UnicodeDammit
text_unicode = UnicodeDammit(text, [None, None], "html", True).unicode_markup
```

But that doesn't work with the json string. Running the string through UnicodeDammit causes an error when I try to json decode it.

The thing is, I'm not even sure that collecting the DOM doesn't handle this issue automatically.

For starters, I would therefore like a series of test webpages to test this. Where one is encoded with utf-8, another with something else, etc. And that uses characters that will look wrong if, for example, you think it's utf-8 but it's not. Note that I don't even bother considering the webpage's stated encoding. This is too often wrong.

Comment: `json.load()` handles Unicode for you; why are you trying to decode this yourself? JSON is a standard that treats strings as Unicode values.

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether I even need to worry about decoding. That's why I would like some test pages. Let's say the webpage is encoded in utf-8. Then the information will be sent to Python as utf-8 encoded, right? Does JSON know this?  What if it's Windows-1252? Does json know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

The browser is responsible for detecting and handling the web page encoding. It'll determine the correct encoding based on the server headers, meta tags in the HTML page and plain guessing if needed. The DOM gives you Unicode data.

JSON handles Unicode data; sending JSON data to your Python process sends appropriately encoded byte data that any decent JSON library will turn back into Unicode values for you. The Python `json` module is such a library.

Just load the data from your JavaScript script with the `json.load()` or `json.loads()` functions **as is**. Your browser will already have used the correct encoding (most likely UTF-8), and the Python `json` module will decode any of the standard encodings used without additional configuration or handling.

Comment: Cool. I thought that might be the case. That's why I was asking for some pages to test it before trying to "solve" it. But if you're sure.

Comment: I am sure. JavaScript / EcmaScript is fully Unicode aware, you are not working with byte strings there either. So is the DOM, etc.